# Getting different results using "cin" for Drill #7 in Chapter 4 of Programming: Principles and Practice using C++ (Stroustrup)

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm busy working through the 2nd edition of Programming: Principles and Practice using C++ (Stroustrup), and getting a problem with reading in values with and without a space between them, then displaying them again.

Can you please point me in the right direction so I can find out why the results differ?

The code compiles fine:  c++ -std=c++11 -o 7 7.cpp

Input test results:

- 10km (works)
- 10 km (works)
- 10 cm (works)
- 10cm (DOES NOT WORK)

Here is the code and also some test input/output with differing results.

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

/*
Add a unit to each double entered; that is, enter values such as 10cm, 2.5in, 5ft, or 3.33m.
Accept the four units: cm, m, in, ft. Assume conversion factors 1m == 100cm, 1in ==
2.54cm, 1ft == 12in. Read the unit indicator into a string. You may consider 12 m (with a
space between the number and the unit) equivalent to 12m (without a space).
*/

int main()
{
    double value = 0.0;
    string unit = "";
    double largest_so_far = 0.0;
    double smallest_so_far = 0.0;
    char resp = 'y';


    // Conversions
    constexpr double m = 100.0;     // 1m = 100cm
    constexpr double in = 2.5;      // 1in = 2.54cm
    constexpr double ft = 12.0;     // 1ft = 12in

    cout << "\n\n\nGive me a floating point value and a unit (ex. 10 cm):   ";
    cin >> value >> unit;

    largest_so_far = value;
    smallest_so_far = value;
    cout << "\nYou gave me the following: " << value << " " << unit << '\n';
    cout << "Thank you.  The largest and smallest so far is now " << value << "\n\n";

    while (resp != '|') {
        cout << "\n\n\nGive me a floating point value:   ";
        cin >> value;

        if (value > largest_so_far)
        {
            largest_so_far = value;
            cout << "You gave me " << largest_so_far << ", the largest so far\n";
        }
        if (value < smallest_so_far) 
        {
            smallest_so_far = value;
            cout << "You gave me " << smallest_so_far << ", the smallest so far\n";
        }


        cout << "Another one? ('|' to stop, any other char for one more) :  ";
        cin >> resp;
    }
}
```

Values that cause failures (such as "10cm"), ends up in the program entering a strange loop.

> OUTPUT: Give me a floating point value: Another one? ('|' to stop, any
>   other char for one more) : Give me a floating point value: Another
>   one? ('|' to stop, any other char for one more) : Give me a floating
>   point value: Another one? ('|' to stop, any other char for one more) :

I have to then press CTRL-C to exit.

A smaller test, thanks to MSalters...

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

/*
    Add a unit to each double entered; that is, enter values such as 10cm, 2.5in, 5ft, or 3.33m.
    Accept the four units: cm, m, in, ft. Assume conversion factors 1m == 100cm, 1in ==
    2.54cm, 1ft == 12in. Read the unit indicator into a string. You may consider 12 m (with a
    space between the number and the unit) equivalent to 12m (without a space).
*/

int main()
{
    double value = 0.0;
    string unit = "";

    cout << "\n\n\nGive me a floating point value and a unit (ex. 10 cm):   ";
    if (cin >> value >> unit)
        cout << "Success, got 2 values\n";
    else
        cout << "Failure!\n";

    cout << "\nYou gave me the following: " << value << " " << unit << '\n';

}
```

~/dev/cpp/ch4/drill/ ./test 
Give me a floating point value and a unit (ex. 10 cm):   10cm
Failure!
You gave me the following: 0

~/dev/cpp/ch4/drill/ ./test 
Give me a floating point value and a unit (ex. 10 cm):   10km
Success, got 2 values
You gave me the following: 10 km

~/dev/cpp/ch4/drill/ ./test 
Give me a floating point value and a unit (ex. 10 cm):   10 km
Success, got 2 values
You gave me the following: 10 km

~/dev/cpp/ch4/drill/ ./test
Give me a floating point value and a unit (ex. 10 cm):   10 cm
Success, got 2 values
You gave me the following: 10 cm

Why does it only fail with strings start start with characters less than "k"?

Comment: Please read the rules on asking good question. When you say " doesn't work", what doesn't work and how exactly does it fail?

Comment: I found that if I use a string between "a" and "j", it fails, but it works fine if the charater for the unit starts with "k" and higher.  Values that cause failures (such as "10cm"), ends up in the program entering a strange loop.  OUTPUT:
Give me a floating point value:   Another one? ('|' to stop, any other char for one more) :  
Give me a floating point value:   Another one? ('|' to stop, any other char for one more) :  
Give me a floating point value:   Another one? ('|' to stop, any other char for one more) :      I have to then press CTRL-C to exit.

Comment: You can edit your questions oon StackOverflow. I've added the relevant part of your comment to your question. You can still add other relevant details.

Comment: N.B. Stroustrup's header is at http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h

Comment: Your results don't make any sense, there is no reason `10cm` should not be read correctly by `cin >> value >> unit` (and when I download the `std_lib_facilities.h` header and try your code it works fine).

Comment: Yep, it seems like a compiler/platform problem.  I'm running on a Mac with the latest compiler suite from Apple.  Just compiled the code on Linux and it worked like a charm.  Very strange.  Thanks Jonathan!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this bug as well, so I asked a duplicate version of this question in the hopes of getting answers.  Here is what I discovered:

- It appears to be an actual bug in one of the standard libraries used by clang.  The bug report for this exact bug is [linked here](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17782).
- The bug appears to be related to conversion specifiers, which would explain why only some letters and not others are affected by it.  A letter which could be a conversion specifier (10.0f for a floating-point number, for example) is parsed differently by the library, and in this instance it affects the ability of cin to properly split a double and a string.
- It's been 2 years and the bug is still unresolved...

I recompiled my own similarly problematic code with -stdlib=libstdc++, which is a different library than the default libc++ library.  It works as it should now, although the letter E still will not be acceptable because it denotes the exponent.

Many thanks to stackoverflow user Petesh for finding the real answer to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Input operations can fail. It's easy to test : `if(cin) /* All went right so far */` or `if (!cin) /* something went wrong */`.

Now your problem is that when something goes wrong, you must clear the fault state before you can accept new input: `cin.clear()`. Also, in your code you should test whether the extraction worked before trying to use `value` and `unit`.

Pro-tip: You can combine this.

```
  if (cin >> value >> unit)
  {
     // Success - value and unit now hold the users input
  }
  else
  {
    // uh oh, that's not good
  }
```